# Change link style and properties using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently looking to take an `OOP` style approach with `javascript`, as I am a beginner level programmer looking to take my `javascript` skills up a notch. The code I have seems not to be working at all, and I have tried differed solutions for a few hours now.

**My Goal**
I would like to accomplish the action of creating click functionality on a page. Where a user clicks on a link and it adds the `CSS` class .active to the link (and of course not adding the class to other links when clicked on).And finally would like when a suer clicks on the same link(active link with the class) again for the class to remove itself and return to its normal state.

Thank you for the help!

**Javascript**

```
var activeState = $(".category-tree-with-article .article-list > li > a, .content-left-bottom li a, .content-right-bottom li a");


          function clickState () {
              this.initEvent();

                 clickState.prototype = {
                     initEvent: function() {

                activeState.on('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var el = $(this);

                    // For class changes
                    activeState.toggleClass('active');
                    el.addClass('active');


                    });
                }

            }//prototype inherit
          } //end function

          clickState();
```

**CSS**

```
a.active {
color:red;
font-family:"Prime";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you should probably stop using your "OOP" style coding

```
var activeState = $(".category-tree-with-article .article-list > li > a, .content-left-bottom li a, .content-right-bottom li a");

activeState.on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    activeState.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Yes, @adeneo says "OOP" in quotes because it's not exactly needed nor is it truly OOP.

Comment: Thank for the response! But may I ask when would you use that style of coding via the front-end? in particular. Or is it based on the situation? Sorry in advance if the questions sound silly. I am just looking to learn more and increase my skills.

Comment: Try to learn a little more about prototyping and object literals, they can both be very useful, but for just adding a few event handlers with jQuery it's totally overkill to do it that way.